# Touch Events on SVG with JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, events, svg, jquery-mobile, touch

I work on a web app which contain SVG in each page, in order to turn a page, I must to use swipe (left and right). Swipe events are detected without any problem on a div or img, etc. But it is impossible to detect touches event on included SVG file :(

I'm using JQuery 1.6.4 and JQuery mobile 1.0b3.

JS :

```js
$('.touchPad object').live('swipeleft swiperight',function(event){
    var currentPage = getVar("page");
    if(currentPage == "0")
    {
        currentPage = 1;
    }

    if (event.type == "swiperight") {
        currentPage ++;
        var page = "page="+currentPage;

        $.mobile.changePage({
        url: "http://asample.com/JQueryMobileTests/index.php",
        type: "get",
        data: page},
        "slide",
        true
        );
    }
    if (event.type == "swipeleft") {
        currentPage --;
        var page = "page="+currentPage;

        $.mobile.changePage({
            url: "http://asample.com/JQueryMobileTests/index.php",
            type: "get", 
            data: page
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML :

```html
<div role-data="page" class="touchPad">
    <div role-data="header"></div>
    <div role-data="content">
        <div>
            <h1>Page : </h1>
            <object type="image/svg+xml" data="pict.SVG" width="800" height="800"></object>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just posted a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415992/how-is-jquery-mobile-interfering-with-my-mouse-touch-listening-on-svg-documents . Cursory looking through the jquery mobile code in Chrome DevTools shows some places where it is stopping propagation of mouse events, but I'm not sure what may be specific to SVG, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem when trying to get swipe Events on svg which contains animation on click. The only way I have found to get the swipe event is to put a div overlaying the svg with opacity at 0 but I lose the click event on SVG then.

```
<svg style="width:100px; height:100px" /><div style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; opacity:0">&nbsp;</div>
```